On Quillen’s Fiber Theorem
I am currently reading Vidit Nanda lectures notes on computational algebraic topology and come accross this version of Quillen's Theorem A :

THEOREM 2.10. (Quillen's Fiber Theorem) Let $f: K \rightarrow L$ be a simplicial map. If the fiber $\tau / f$ is contractible for every simplex $\tau$ in $L$, then the induced continuous map $|f|:|K| \rightarrow|L|$ admits a homotopy inverse $G:|L| \rightarrow|K|$; and in particular, $K$ and $L$ are homotopy equivalent.

Interestingly, in the proof of theorem 2.10, the homotopy inverse $G$ (coming from carriers lemma) verifies, $G(|\tau|) \subset |\tau / f|$ for all $\tau\in L$.
Theorem 2.10 can be generalized for topological spaces under additional assumptions (as in Smale, 1957). Consider $f:X\rightarrow Y$, X and Y being topological spaces (satisfying assumptions of Smale, 1957) and suppose that the fibers $f^{-1}(y)$ are contractible for all $y\in Y$, then there exists an inverse homotopy $G:Y\rightarrow X$.
I wonder if we can impose furthermore a similar property on $G$, i.e. something like : for all $y\in Y$, $G(y)\subset f^{-1}(y)$ ?
EDIT : The link to Vindit Nandat lectures note : https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/nanda/cat/Lecture%2002%20Homotopy.pdf
